# Condicional y calculo de un valor en SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos

**Tengo el siguiente problema:** Aumentar el precio unitario en un `15%` pero de aquellos artículos cuyo precio unitario sea inferior a `20`.

Tener en cuenta además que la descripción comience con su legajo

Solución:

```
UPDATE ARTICULOS
SET pre_unitario = pre_unitario + pre_unitario*0.15
where pre_unitario < 20

SELECT cod_articulo, descripcion, pre_unitario from articulos
WHERE pre_unitario < 20
```

¿Ésta solución es la adecuada?

Comment: Y la probaste? y cual es el problema?

Comment: te falta agregar la condición de la descripción...

Comment: y como le agrego la condicion ?

Comment: Es buena práctica en `SQL` emplear las cláusulas en mayúsculas `SELECT`, `WHERE`, `FROM`, `GROUP BY`... para identificar rápidamente que son columnas, parámetros, condiciones y la fuente que se ingesta a partir de la cláusula `FROM`... Por ejemplo se observa la tabla `articulos` en minúscula pero en la primera línea va en mayúscula... `ARTICULOS` o las frase `UPDATE ARTICULOS` es un comentario y se obvio comentarla con `--`, `#`,...  Estás dudas se pueden disminuir si también se indica en las etiquetas, cuál `SQL` estás empleado, `SQLite`, `MySQL`,...

Comment: Sí estás empezando en el mundo de `SQL` te sugiero que para este caso revises  la cláusula `CASE WHEN condicion THEN hacer_si_condicion_es_verdadera ELSE hacer_si_no_se_cumple_condicion END AS pre_unitario`... hay otras formas de lograr lo que buscas... pero eso dependerá del `motor SQL` que estes usando.